# What if the matrix is not invertible in the Alternating Least Squares Algorithm

Tags: regression, matrix-decomposition

We want to factorize $R_{n\times m}\approx X^{T}_{n\times k}Y_{k\times m}.$ The following update rules are given [here](http://stanford.edu/~rezab/classes/cme323/S15/notes/lec14.pdf):

$$x_u = \left(\sum_{r_{ui}\in r_{u*}} y_i y_i^T + \lambda I_k\right)^{-1} \sum_{r_{ui}\in r_{u*}} r_{ui} y_i \quad(u = 1, ..., n)$$
and 
$$y_i = \left(\sum_{r_{ui}\in r_{*i}} x_u x_u^T + \lambda I_k\right)^{-1} \sum_{r_{ui}\in r_{*u}} r_{ui} x_u \quad(i = 1, ..., m).$$

I have written the following update method in C++ using Eigen, with the assumption that 
$$\text{Matrix}_{\text{authors}\times \text{papers}} = P^{T}_{\text{authors}\times \text{lat_feat}}Q_{\text{lat_feat}\times \text{papers}}.$$

```
void update_PQ()
{   Eigen::MatrixXd lambda_I_k = lambda*Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(lat_feat, lat_feat);


    for(int c = 0; c < authors; c++)
    {
        Eigen::VectorXd s2(lat_feat);
        Eigen::MatrixXd s1(lat_feat,lat_feat);


        for (int k=0; k < matrix.outerSize(); ++k)
        {
            for (Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(matrix,k); it; ++it)
                {
                    int u = it.row();
                    int i = it.col();
                    if (c == u)
                        {
                            int mat_val = it.value();
                            s2 += matrix.coeffRef(u,i)*Q.col(i);
                            s1 += Q.col(i)*Q.col(i).transpose();
                         }
                }
        }
       P.col(c) = (s1+lambda_I_k).inverse()*s2;
    }


    for(int c = 0; c < papers; c++)
    {
        Eigen::VectorXd s2(lat_feat);
        Eigen::MatrixXd s1(lat_feat,lat_feat);


        for (int k=0; k < matrix.outerSize(); ++k)
        {
            for (Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(matrix,k); it; ++it)
                {
                    int u = it.row();
                    int i = it.col();
                    if (c == i)
                        {
                            int mat_val = it.value();
                            s2 += matrix.coeffRef(u,i)*P.col(u);
                            s1 += P.col(u)*P.col(u).transpose();
                         }
                }
        }

       Q.col(c) = (s1+lambda_I_k).inverse()*s2;
    }
}
```

The problem is that after a few iterations I get that inverse of the matrix does not exist. This fill $P$ and $Q$ with nan values. How does one get around this problem?

Comment: Perhaps try increasing $\lambda$; apart from the role of regularisation, it will help to numerically condition the matrices.

Comment: I have used $\lambda = 0.1.$ Do you think it's a good choice?

Comment: That might depend on your data. I would recommend trying with increased $\lambda$ to see if the problem persists. That way you can either identify/eliminate it as the source of your issue.

Comment: @rzch 's comments are spot on (+1). The other things I would recommend you check is: 1. consider using different $\lambda$'s for different factor families. 2. Investigate how the condition number of $P$ and $Q$ changes with each iteration. Probably one of the fails before the other. 3. Consider early stopping.